# Issue with delayed mailers in rails using sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

everyone. I have some troubles with action mailers using sidekiq on production. After deploying the code to prod(using capistrano) mailers are seems to be using the old code. And it happens in random way. I have already tried to restart sidekiq manually on server. But no joy. Probably someone had some simillar problem and can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not restarted apache/nginx. That's why it doesn't affect your changes.